# ¿Como solucionar problema con admob no crea los anuncios, pero aparece como impreso?

Tags: android, admob

**Hola a todos**

**Mi problema es el siguiente:** actualmente tengo un problema con admob de que cuando trato de que se visualice un anuncio, pero no se muestra, lo que me he percatado es que el sistema envía la solicitud, porque se almacena como impresión en el panel de administrador de aplicaciones de admob.

Mi código actual es en el .xml o el layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.virtualdisk.INS" >

      <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
      android:id="@+id/adView"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      ads:adSize="BANNER"
      ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-1765002374395487/9026293652"
      android:minHeight="90dp" >

  </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="124dp"
    android:text="Iniciar" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:max="100" />
```

Y en la clase es:

```
       AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Y el espacio que dejo para el anuncio es:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si notan donde fallo o conocen otras formas. Por favor comunicarmelo.

Comment: ¿Has probado en un dispositivo? Eso parece una captura del emulador, y los anuncios a veces no funcionan en el emulador

Comment: Los anuncios no se cargarán en ambientes de desarrollo, y si es el caso, puede terminar en la eliminación de tu cuenta por infringir las normas. Prueba con los id de bloques de anuncio de prueba que puedes encontrar [acá](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads?hl=es-419)

Answer (score 0):

Tu código y definición dentro del layout no tiene problemas, pero estas usando un emulador, seguramente necesitas definir:

[.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdRequest)

ejemplo:

```
 AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
   .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
   .build();
mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

---

> [DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdRequest)   El id de dispositivo para emuladores para ser
>   usado con addTestDevice(String).

Comment: En realidad no uso emulador, si no mi teléfono, porque es mas rapido que el emulador. Gracias